# Auto-deleted Repeated sections

Tags: orbeon

I created a Orbeon form that contains repeated sections that are filled in with data saved under form-resources in the source code. As usual, I use the functionality 'calculated value' with a xPath expression to fill in a field. 
After I created the form, I made a survey. If I close the form without saving it and reopen it,
then no repeated sections are displayed anymore. 
Is there a way to avoid the deletion of repeated sections in this case?

Thanks a lot for your help.

bjn

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer your question without running a concrete example with detailed steps. Can you share one?

Comment: Also, screenshots of what you are seeing can help.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I'll add a sample source code as well as a screenshot soon.